# PDFKit - PDFDocument object increase file size while saving

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit, pdfdocument

I am working on a PDF app which imports pdf document from Mail app. After importing the file (2 MB) in the app and opening it using PDFKit PDFDocument class the file size increases to 35 MB. I checked it by using PDFDocument.dataRepresentation() method and saving it in documents directory.
Can someone help me understand why does the file size increases by such a huge number? What is the best way to handle this situation?